# Loading data from a pointer and writing it back in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, memory, agora.io

I'm building a video streaming app using [Agora SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/flutter/v5.3.0/API/rtc_api_overview.html) (for Flutter). I also use a native-layer [Raw Video Data plugin](https://github.com/AgoraLibrary/flutter_agora_rtc_rawdata/) as a dependency, which gives me access to raw YUV420 frame buffers before they're encoded. I can access them via a Swift interface.

I need to write code that intercepts a raw video frame, stores it, and then overwrites the subsequent frame with the previously stored image data. Then intercepts the third frame, and writes it over the 4th, and so on.

The plugin repo has a demo of how to work with raw frames.

**iOS** ([source](https://github.com/AgoraLibrary/flutter_agora_rtc_rawdata/blob/master/ios/Classes/SwiftAgoraRtcRawdataPlugin.swift)) (this demo code just colors the captured video green):

```
public func onCapture(_ videoFrame: AgoraVideoFrame) -> Bool {
    memset(videoFrame.uBuffer, 0, Int(videoFrame.uStride * videoFrame.height) / 2)
    memset(videoFrame.vBuffer, 0, Int(videoFrame.vStride * videoFrame.height) / 2)
    return true
}
```

`videoFrame.uBuffer` is an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`, as defined in [AgoraVideoFrame.h](https://github.com/AgoraLibrary/flutter_agora_rtc_rawdata/blob/master/ios/Base/AgoraVideoFrame.h).

**First try** (paints half of the whole frame into the color of the top-left pixel):

```
// first frame callback
bufferedFrameY = videoFrame.yBuffer.load(as: Int32.self)
bufferedFrameU = videoFrame.uBuffer.load(as: Int32.self)
bufferedFrameV = videoFrame.vBuffer.load(as: Int32.self)

//.. 2nd frame callback
memset(videoFrame.yBuffer, bufferedFrameY, Int(videoFrame.yStride * videoFrame.height))
memset(videoFrame.uBuffer, bufferedFrameU, Int(videoFrame.uStride * videoFrame.height / 2))
memset(videoFrame.vBuffer, bufferedFrameV, Int(videoFrame.vStride * videoFrame.height / 2))
```

**Second try** (does nothing at all):

```
// first frame callback
bufferedFrameY = videoFrame.yBuffer.load(as: Int32.self)
bufferedFrameU = videoFrame.uBuffer.load(as: Int32.self)
bufferedFrameV = videoFrame.vBuffer.load(as: Int32.self)

//.. 2nd frame callback
videoFrame.yBuffer.storeBytes(of: bufferedFrameY, as: Int32.self)
videoFrame.uBuffer.storeBytes(of: bufferedFrameU, as: Int32.self)
videoFrame.vBuffer.storeBytes(of: bufferedFrameV, as: Int32.self)
```

How should I approach this to solve the problem?

---

Comment: The reason I need this is because sometimes I need FPS <= 1, but AFAICT, Agora treats such low frame rate as a signal that something's wrong with the network, or the encoder, and starts to drop frames outright, and behave in undesirable ways. So I want to circumvent that by setting the FPS to 2, but encode each frame twice, and see what happens.

Comment: Are you asking a `Swift` question or a `Kotlin` & `Swift` question?